# SQL query to return max record

Tags: sql, max

I have two tables with the following fields

```
Order Header
TransID, InvoiceDate

Order Detail
TransID, PartID
```

I am trying to write a query that will return those parts which have not had an order header entry since a specific date.

The header table has 1 row per transid, where the detail table can have multiple rows.

Here is what I have been trying:

```
select h.transid,partid, h.invoicedate
from tblaphistdetail d
right outer join tblaphistheader h
on d.transid = h.transid
where partid <> ''
and h.invoicedate <= dateadd(yyyy,-2,getdate())
group by h.transid,partid, invoicedate
order by partid
```

This returns those parts and transids which are prior to the specific date (2 years prior to today), but the parts also have transids which have an invoicedate within the last 2 years.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you want to include the parts for which there have been no orders at all?

Comment: That should not be an issue as these 2 tables are the header and detail tables for orders.  Theoretically, I should tie in the table which houses ALL items.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
and h.invoicedate <= dateadd(yyyy,-2,getdate())
```

to:

```
and h.transid NOT IN (SELECT transid
                      FROM tblaphisheader
                      WHERE invoicedate > dateadd(yyyy,-2,getdate()))
```

UPDATE:

```
select h.transid,partid, h.invoicedate
from tblaphistdetail d
inner join tblaphistheader h
on d.transid = h.transid
where partid <> ''
and partid NOT IN (SELECT partid
                   FROM tblaphisdetail d
                   INNER JOIN tblaphistheader h
                   ON d.transid - h.transid
                   WHERE invoicedate > dateadd(yyyy,-2,getdate()))
group by h.transid,partid, invoicedate
order by partid
```

Comment: That is still returning parts which have an invoice date within the last 2 years.

Comment: OK, updated. I got confused by your use of `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, which implies that you wanted headers with no corresponding details, which would make it meaningless to test part ID.

Comment: Need to add a layer of complexity to this, sorry.  Now I need to tie in the Item table.  This table is a list of ALL items.  They may or may not been a part of an order.  The join would be item.itemid = detail.partid.  Does this look correct?

Comment: `select h.transid,i.itemid, h.invoicedate
from tblaphistdetail d
inner join tblinitem i
on i.itemid = d.partid
inner join tblaphistheader h
on d.transid = h.transid
where partid <> ''
and partid NOT IN (SELECT partid
                   FROM tblaphistdetail d
                   INNER JOIN tblaphistheader h
                   ON d.transid = h.transid
                   WHERE invoicedate > dateadd(yyyy,-2,getdate()))
group by h.transid,itemid, invoicedate
order by itemid`

Comment: You only need to do that in the main query, it shouldn't be needed in the subquery.

Comment: It's hard to read that unformatted query, but I think it's right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include only parts for which orders exist but not since a specific date, you could try the following:

```
SELECT
  d.PartID,
  MAX(h.InvoiceDate) AS LastOrdered
FROM
  dbo.tblaphistdetail AS d
INNER JOIN
  dbo.tblaphistheader AS h ON d.TransID = h.TransID
GROUP BY
  d.PartID
HAVING
  MAX(h.InvoiceDate) < @SpecificDate
;
```

If there's a `Parts` table with all the parts available and you want to include those that have never been included in an invoice, here's another solution:

```
SELECT
  p.PartID,
  MAX(h.InvoiceDate) AS LastOrdered
FROM
  dbo.tblaphistdetail AS d
INNER JOIN
  dbo.tblaphistheader AS h ON d.TransID = h.TransID
RIGHT JOIN
  dbo.Parts AS p ON d.PartID = p.PartID
GROUP BY
  p.PartID
HAVING
  MAX(h.InvoiceDate) < @SpecificDate
  OR MAX(h.InvoiceDate) IS NULL
;
```